# I'm getting "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong." error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I'm getting this error when i try to update-databse a migration.
The migration content is as follows:

```
namespace MyProject.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class ComingBackToPReviosStage : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Movies", "Genre_Id", "dbo.Genres");
            DropIndex("dbo.Movies", new[] { "Genre_Id" });
            DropColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Movies", name: "Genre_Id", newName: "GenreId");
            AlterColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Movies", "GenreId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", "dbo.Genres", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", "dbo.Genres");
            DropIndex("dbo.Movies", new[] { "GenreId" });
            AlterColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", c => c.Int());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", c => c.Byte(nullable: false));
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Movies", name: "GenreId", newName: "Genre_Id");
            AddColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", c => c.Byte(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Movies", "Genre_Id");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Movies", "Genre_Id", "dbo.Genres", "Id");
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a column to a table Movies and i want to make it a foreign key.

Comment: and which of those operations raises that error?

Comment: DropColumn("dbo.Movies", "GenreId");
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Movies", name: "Genre_Id", newName: "GenreId");